# Foreign key with a static value

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables.

The two tables tab1 and tab2 contains some data.
The calender links the data to a date.

Is it possible to create a Foreign Key containing the id and a static kat?

I image a entry in "calendar" with the id 1 from "tab1"  in context with kat = "tab1".
"tab1" and "tab" can contain same ids.

Is this possible or is it a realy bad database design?

**The Database structure:**

[image: Database structure]

Comment: If I read this right you want to use a key that combines (concatenates actually) the key of one table with the key of another table?

Comment: If my understanding is correct, then you want to not do this the way you proposed, but rather use a bridge table (also known as a junction table).  See here for more details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

Comment: This is not the full way. the key kat is not stored in the database - it should depend on a free text like "tab1". There is no link between "tab1" and "tab2"

Comment: Instead, perhaps consider storing FK of `calendar` in `tab1` and `tab2`?

Comment: There doesn't have to be a link between tab1 and tab2.  A bridge table makes it so you can relate as many tabs as you need to to the calendar (any number of calendars actually).  All you need to do this is store a record that has the id for the tab (say tab1) and the id of the calendar (say calendar1).
so your bridge table might contain:
calender_id,tab_id (these are the column names)
calendar1, tab1
calendar1, tab2
then you can join these tables in a query to get all of the tabs related to the particular calendar you want.
Concatenating keys is a really, really bad idea, by the way.

Comment: Sure there must not be a link. With this link i want to be sure the entry in calender (connected to tab1) has an existing entry in tab1. the element from tab1 can be linked on more than one day in calendar. Do you think the relation with a filed "kategorie" is a bad idea?